# Dynamically Set Size of Items in a Row

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I made the mistake of putting in a lot of work with my code solely on iOS first and then when I went to check the Android app the formatting was all messed up, but still fine on iOS.

Below is what each looks like.
[iOS formatting looks fine,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTsfd.png) [Android formatting is off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aE7JG.png)

So in the little box there that is a container housing a row that houses the icon and the text. When my firebase side updates it turns it into a card to it is clickable.

My problem is I'm already using AutoSizeText and it didn't help me in this situation and I've tried a solution of using a layout builder to set a max size constraint but that didn't do it either.

Any idea how to set it so that both the text and the icon size are set dynamically or even just the icon size is set dynamically?

My current code below:

```
class AlertWidget extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('alerts')
        .where('access',
            arrayContains: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)
        .where('read', isEqualTo: false)
        //.orderBy('createdAt', descending: true)
        .snapshots(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data.docs.length <= 0) {
        return Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                topRight: Radius.circular(10),
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(10)),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                spreadRadius: 5,
                blurRadius: 7,
                offset: Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
              ),
            ],
          ),
          height: 60.0,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              SizedBox(width: 10.0),
              Icon(
                Icons.check_box,
                color: Colors.green,
                size: 60,
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 10.0),
              AutoSizeText(
                "No Current Messages or Alerts",
                maxLines: 1,
                maxFontSize: 20,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              //if (snapshot.hasData) SizedBox(width: 45),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
      Alert alert = Alert.fromFirestore(snapshot.data.docs.first);
      return Card(
        //height: 60.0,
        child: InkWell(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                getIcon(snapshot),
                SizedBox(width: 15.0),
                Text(
                  "New Alert for Your Patient",
                  style:
                      TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                //if (snapshot.hasData) SizedBox(width: 45),
                if (snapshot.hasData) Icon(Icons.arrow_right, size: 50)
              ],
            ),
            onTap: () {}),
        elevation: 12,
      );
    });
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap your `AutoSizeText` widget with `Expanded` to constrain the size of the text so `AutoSizeText` can then resize it.

Here is some [explanation](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text) from `AutoSizeText`:

> Because Row and other widgets like Container, Column or ListView do
> not constrain their children, the text will overflow. You can fix this
> by constraining the AutoSizeText. Wrap it with Expanded in case of Row
> and Column or use a SizedBox or another widget with fixed width (and
> height).

```
 AutoSizeText(
     "No Current Messages or Alerts",
     maxLines: 1,
     maxFontSize: 20,
     style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
```

should change to :

```
Expanded(
    child:
        AutoSizeText(
           "No Current Messages or Alerts",
           maxLines: 1,
           maxFontSize: 20,
           style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
    ),
```

Comment: I added this to my code and it worked exactly as you said it would. It fixed the overflow like I needed. Only problem I have now is that the Icon looks freakishly large next to the font. Thank you!

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of this? Also, how would you prefer the icon and text resize dynamically?

Comment: Sure can! [Android Icon](https://imgur.com/a/zYgeiRS) Here is the Android Icon next to the newly sized text. The text sizing is seems to be good after your suggested update. The icon just looks a bit large next to the text now. on iOS the sizing is good because I set the static size of the icon when making the iOS app. The icon changed here just because I updated my firebase db but fixing the size on this icon will also fix it on the green checkmark that was shown above.

Comment: What I'll suggest is to make your icon size a function of your screen width. `size: MediaQuery.of (context).size.width * 0.05 (or whatever number works)`. That way you can control how it scales.